# javascript date minute with leading zero: slice vs short if

Tags: javascript

Javascript code for getting the minutes of the current time.

```
var dateObj = new Date();
dateObj.setMinutes(1); // Setting the minutes to "1".
var minutes = dateObj.getMinutes(); // Returns "1".
```

What would be better speed optimized code?

```
alert( ('0'+minutes).slice(-2) ); // Returns "01".
```

or

```
alert( (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes ); // Returns "01".
```

Comment: I recommend you check out jsperf.com - you may want to throw this method in there as well: `minutes.replace(/([\d]{1})/, '0$1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `(minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes` is about 3 times as fast as `('0'+minutes).slice(-2)` in my limited testing.

http://jsfiddle.net/v0jk8mhq/[image]

Comment: Habit.  It keeps the global namespace clean, among other things. Google Immediately-Invoked Function Expression in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran it chrome performance, and

```
alert( ('0'+minutes).slice(-2) );
```

came out the fastest which I think is due to the fact that there was no evaluation taking place.

The total time it took was 1265.4ms, vs the first method which was 2225ms